# Another program movie rebus

Tags: rebus, movies

Here's my take on the subject:

```
a = new Date()
b = new Date(a.getTime()+24*3600*1000)
all:
a.getDay() != b.getDay()
```

Which movie quote is hidden in the above `Javascript` code?

Comment: It's simple, the answer is `true`. After all, that's what the JS console tells me...

Comment: @CᴏɴᴏʀO'Bʀɪᴇɴ, Of course, great movie quotes carry great truths.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> "After all, tomorrow is another day."
>
>  Classic Gone With The Wind line, the code is comparing tomorrow to today to show they are different, and it happens after "all"

Answer (score 6):

The best I can do:

> [After all, tomorrow is another day](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R-OoIvgtuzs)